# Using Enum as Object keys

Tags: javascript

I have an Enum:

```
   const ingredients = {
      BREAD_BOTTOM: 'BreadBottom',
      BREAD_TOP: 'BreadTop',
      MEAT: 'Meat',
      BACON: 'Bacon',
      CHEESE: 'Cheese',
      SALAD: 'Salad'
   };
```

Now I want to create a list of ingredients using this Enum, something like:

```
    listOfIngredients: {
      ingredients.BREAD_TOP: 1,
      ingredients.BACON: 1,
      ingredients.CHEESE: 2,
      ingredients.MEAT: 2,
      ingredients.BREAD_BOTTOM: 1,
    }
```

I try some variations such as `${ingredients.BREAD_TOP}` but I cannot make the list of ingredients have as key the Enum values

Comment: Well, it's not *really* an "enum"; it's an object with string-valued properties. You can use `[ ]` however to extract the property values in the second object literal.

Comment: What do you want the keys to be? The value of the enum?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can wrap the keys in `[]` to evaluate their value before using them as keys

```
const listOfIngredients: {
      [ingredients.BREAD_TOP]: 1,
      [ingredients.BACON]: 1,
      [ingredients.CHEESE]: 2,
      [ingredients.MEAT]: 2,
      [ingredients.BREAD_BOTTOM]: 1,
}
```

To access a value, just do:

```
console.log(listOfIngredients[ingredients.BREAD_TOP]);
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
let ingredients = {
  BREAD_BOTTOM: 'BreadBottom',
  BREAD_TOP: 'BreadTop',
  MEAT: 'Meat',
  BACON: 'Bacon',
  CHEESE: 'Cheese',
  SALAD: 'Salad'
};

const listOfIngredients= {
      [ingredients.BREAD_TOP]: 1,
      [ingredients.BACON]: 1,
      [ingredients.CHEESE]: 2,
      [ingredients.MEAT]: 2,
      [ingredients.BREAD_BOTTOM]: 1
};

console.log(listOfIngredients[ingredients.BREAD_TOP]);
```